# Animate button click and color

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate, photoshop

[image]

I made this button in Photoshop. I have plenty of graphic UI experience, but not much coding besides python and html/css.

I figured I would use javascript to animate the button being clicked and change color. I am very much a beginner and do not know my next step. Such as if I shouldn't create the button in photoshop but make it from scratch with code?

Or if I make a separate image that's red and it changes back and forth between images? But I'm not sure if that process would look smooth when it's clicked. This is all for a dashboard gui web app. I was playing around just trying to get a simple button to change colors using only code but I'm lost. I haven't been able to find anything related to what I'm doing which I think is crazy because how common UI's are created in Photoshopped and animated with code.

Javascript

```
    var button = document.querySelector('.button');

    button.onclick = function () {
      if (backgroundColor == green) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = red";
}
```

CSS

```
.button {
  &:hover {
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
  }
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few ways you could accomplish that effect. You could have two images saved as two separate files, two images in one file next to each other and move them via css background position, have just one image and change the color of it using css, build the button using just css, etc

Comment: The two image approach is probably the most common, but as you've alluded to, could be a bit laggy on first use if you don't preload the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would first attempt to do this with HTML & CSS since it’ll be the easiest to maintain down the line (i.e. need a different size color? just a tweak a value in CSS).

From your description it sounds like you are effectively making a styled checkbox. You want to use semantic elements (i.e. not `<div>` and `<span>`) wherever possible to improve the experience for screen readers and keyboard-only users. So create a checkbox in HTML, hide it, then style the element after it based on the value of the hidden checkbox.

```css
/* hide the native element */
.your-button input {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* disable user selection */
.your-button,
.your-button * {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}

/* The grey button */
your-button-elem {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(0, 0%, 100%), hsl(0, 0%, 80%));
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
  transition: 60ms;
}

/* The colored status ring */
your-button-elem::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  right: -16px;
  bottom: -16px;
  left: -16px;
  background: hsl(162, 0%, 69%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
  z-index: -1;
}

/* The dimple ontop of the button */
your-button-elem::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: 26px;
  bottom: 26px;
  left: 26px;
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(0, 0%, 80%), hsl(0, 0%, 98%));
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 6px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
}

/* The checked state */
input:checked ~ your-button-elem::before {
  background: hsl(162, 52%, 69%);
}

/* The pressed state */
input:active ~ your-button-elem,
your-button-elem:active {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
}

/* The focused state */
.your-button input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input:focus ~ your-button-elem::before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3),
                    0 0 0 4px hsla(200, 100%, 50%, 0.3);
}
input:focus ~ your-button-elem:hover::before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
}


/***** Setup *******************/
* { margin:0; padding:0 }
html, body { height:100% }
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<label class="your-button">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <your-button-elem></your-button-elem>
</label>
```

Comment: Hats off! This looks great, looks like you did enjoy the challenge ;)

Comment: is there a way to do this without changing the z-index?

Comment: Yeah I think the styles on your-button-elem should be swapped with the styles on your-button-elem::before

Answer (score 5):

Here is an idea how you can create this button using CSS then you can easily adjust color, dimension, apply smooth effect, animation, etc:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top, #f2f2f2, #ccc, #b3b3b3);
  position: relative;
  border: 12px solid #96c9b9;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  bottom: 22%;
  right: 22%;
  left: 22%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:1px solid #cecece;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom, #f2f2f2, #ccc, #aaa);
}

.button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 9px #757373;
}

.button:hover {
 border-color:#9fdecb;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
```

Comment: never tried to implement one image button by pure css before. Perfect, your css button is almost same as OP's image.

Comment: @Sphinx and by tweaking some colors we can have exactly the same ;) but the main purspose is to highlight the different tricks i use to obtain the button then it should be easy to adjust colors

Comment: Excellent.. + 1

Comment: Heh, looks like we took roughly the same approach. From the question though it looks like he’s trying to build a toggle, which this is not. This is also unusable to keyboard / screen reader users.

Comment: @Zaqx well, we are no meant to do all the job of the OP :) ... the main thing in his question is that he's not a good with CSS to create such thing, so my answer highlight some CSS trick in order to do it then it's up to him to use it in order to create any functionnal button he want, using input, using js, etc etc

Answer (score 3):

```js
 function btnclick() {
   var glow = document.getElementById("gldiv");
   var dimp = document.getElementById("dimple");
   var d = document.getElementById("dlght")
   if (dimp.style.display == "block") {
    glow.style.background = "#c9969d";
    dimp.style.display = "none";
    d.style.display = "none";
   }
   else {
    glow.style.background = "#96c9b9";
    dimp.style.display = "block";
    d.style.display = "block";
   }
  }
```

```css
 body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   background: #e7dede;
  }
  
  .mainbg {
   background: #e7dede;
   padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .gdiv {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 50px;
   background-color: #fff0;
   padding: 10px;
   transition: .5s all ease;
  }
  
  .glowdiv {
   margin: 100px auto;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #c9969d;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px #00000055;
   border-radius: 50px;
   transition: .5s all ease;
  }
  
  .gdiv:hover {
   background-color: #fff3;
  }
  
  .btninshadow {
   box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 3px #6d81a5;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 50px;
   padding: 15px;
  }
  
  .btndiv {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: linear-gradient(115deg, #f3f3f7, #b1bace);
   border-radius: 50px;
   box-shadow: -1px 3px 10px #00000099;
  }
  
  .btndimple {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: linear-gradient(115deg, #f3f3f7, #b1bace);
   border-radius: 50px;
   box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px #6d81a5cc;
   display: none;
   transition: .5s all ease;
  }
  
  .btndimlgt {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #fff;
   border-radius: 50px;
   display: none;
   transition: .5s all ease;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="mainbg">
  <div class="glowdiv" id="gldiv">
   <div class="gdiv">
    <div class="btndiv" onclick="btnclick();">
     <div class="btninshadow">
      <div class="btndimlgt" id="dlght">
       <div class="btndimple" id="dimple"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow dude! Just saw this. I like it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript you can use css:

```
 .button {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

.button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For normal button, your codes are very closed, just need to fix some syntax issues.

If you'd like to change the color of the image button, you can use the filter of css. But be aware of `css:filter` only being supporeted by mordern browser.

**Update:**

@Temani Afif already implemented one perfect css button, so I considered using SVG to do same thing. It might not be a good solution, just share what I tried.

**PS:** I don't have many aesthetics cells, so the SVG looks ugly, lol.

Below is one sample:

```js
// for normal button
var button = document.querySelector('.button');
button.style['background-color'] = "green"; // or button.style.backgroundColor
button.onclick = function () {
  console.log(this.style['background-color']);  // or this.style.backgroundColor
  if (this.style['background-color'] == 'green') {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
  else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
}

//for image button
const imageStyles = ['saturate', 'grayscale', 'invert'];
var imageIndex = 0;
document.querySelector('.imgbutton').onclick = function() {
  console.log(this.className);
  this.className =imageStyles[imageIndex++%imageStyles.length];
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.saturate { 
  filter: saturate(4); 
}
.grayscale {
  filter: grayscale(90%); 
}

.invert { 
  filter: invert(90%); 
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ svg circle:nth-child(1) {
  fill: black;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>

<a class="button">Click me</a>
<img style="width:100px;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/61NAY.png" class="imgbutton" alt="Click Me" title="click me!"/>

<label>
 <input type="checkbox" style="display:none"/>
 <svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle id="circle1" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="#8dbab1" stroke-width="9" fill="#eaf2f0"></circle>
   <circle id="circle2" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" stroke="#edf9f5" stroke-width="2" fill="#d1d6d4"></circle>
 </svg> 
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Beautiful! This helps a ton. I have one more reaally stupid question and I tried to find an answer to linking it. But I made a script.js file with the js in it, a style.css sheet, and I'm trying to get the javascript to work and I can't seem to get the html to reference it using: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

Comment: @JackHudgins, is your script.js under same folder with your html? check this url [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599289/i-cant-figure-out-why-my-javascript-file-wont-display-when-linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599289/i-cant-figure-out-why-my-javascript-file-wont-display-when-linked)

Comment: It's under the same folder and I tried doing it on my local server too but it won't work. Have tried using that solution.

Comment: @JackHudgins, you can create one new question for this question. We need enough context for the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to alternate between two colors using the DOM:

```
        button.onclick = function () {
           const color = document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor;
           if (color =="green") document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor ="red";
else  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor ="green";
    }
```